# Multiple calculations, display on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure what to call this to be honest but we shall see if you get the point by my question.

I have a table on a standard HTML page and using Javascript/jQuery I have some calculations.

## Example:

```
function addThem() {
    var result;

    result = userInput + 100;
    return result;
}
```

This is just an example of a simple (uncompleted) function I have. What I want to do is grab a user input and then display the result in a table. So as far as I know I can do this using:

```
document.getElementById("addThemResult").innerHTML = result;
```

and the HTML would be:

```
<td id="addThemResult"></td>
```

I have done this before and it works. Now my problem is, I will have multiple fields for the same thing but have no idea how to accept multiple user inputs and display them using the same function.

## Live Example

I bet im not making much sense so I will try create a little example.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhJHK/1/)

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>
            <input id="money1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="money2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Money Left</td>
        <td id="moneyleft1"></td>
        <td id="moneyleft2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        cal();
    });
});

function cal() {
    var cal1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("money1").value);

    result = cal1 - 100;
    document.getElementById("moneyleft1").innerHTML = "£" + result;
}
```

So if we look at the example I made, if you input a value into "money - one" input it will display the result below. What I now want to do is get the result in "money - two" using the second input and using the same function.

How would I go about doing this, please note that what I need to use this for is a lot bigger and has around 6 rows of this.

I hope this made some sense and any help would be great, it maybe a simple thing but I cant seem to get my head around it.

## Update:

As I ran into more I needed to do it has changed from what I thought it was. Now there are more inputs and they are pretty much everywhere. Some of them need to be used in the calculations and others will display the result in a field

[**UPDATE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhJHK/14/)

As you can see the results will always change no matter what input you type in. I need that to stop and I want to point them where they should go and when they should change.

E.g:

```
Money = 10000 so the field "cal1" for that column changes.
```

If I then type in the miles input:

```
Miles = 2300 the "cal1" field should not change and "cal2" field should have the result.
```

I can only think to do it this way but it feels with a cheat.

[**CHEAT WAY?**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhJHK/15/)

So putting class on each of the inputs then keyup on that class.

**Edit:** I am still not able to get the values from the inputs in the same column. Also I think my "cheat" way will not work.

## Update 2:

Right I made a better example, that was my fault because I didn;t explain it as well as it should have been.

In this example you will see that there are multiple inputs but they only work in the first column (due to no knowing how to make the others work). So now I need to get that working in ALL over columns using the same functions.

[**UPDATE 2 EXAMPE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J4ALs/)

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option1</th>
        <th>Option2</th>
        <th>Option3</th>
        <th>Option4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="money" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Upfront</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="upfront" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Overall Price</td>
        <td id="overallPrice"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="discount" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dicount Price</td>
        <td id="discountPrice"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        overallPrice();
        discountPrice();
    });
});

function overallPrice() {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("money").value);
    cal2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("upfront").value);
    result = cal1 - cal2;
    document.getElementById("overallPrice").innerHTML = "£" + result;
    return result;
}

function discountPrice() {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("discount").value);
    cal2 = overallPrice();
    result = cal2 - cal1;
    document.getElementById("discountPrice").innerHTML = "£" + result;
}
```

Its a little different from my first due to the extra rows with inputs. The answers so far do not make it possible to fill in the second set of inputs in a column.

Note: There will be more then 2 sets of inputs, this is just an example.

Comment: Should the second `id="moneyleft1"` be `id="moneyleft2"`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, yes it should I will change that now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you need to call `overallPrice` in the keyup handler when it's called by `discountPrice`?

Comment: @Barmar Good point but that's a minor "problem"? Compared to what huge problem this question is being to me. I have no idea why I cant get my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for any number of `<td>`'s .. just that the last table row should have an id.. in my case that is `total`

```
...
 <tr id="total">
    <td>Money Left</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
....
```

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').keyup(function () {
     cal(this);
  });
 });

 function cal(obj) {

   var result = parseFloat(obj.value) - 100;
   var tdPos=$(obj).parent().index();
   $('#total').find('td:eq('+tdPos+')').html("£" + result);
}
```

**just incase if you cannot modify the HTML element...without the id , your selector should be**

```
 function cal(obj) {
   var cal1, result;
   cal1 = parseFloat(obj.value);

   result = cal1 - 100;
   var tdPos=$(obj).parent().index();
   //$('#total').find('td:eq('+tdPos+')').html("£" + result);
   //here
   $(obj).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq('+tdPos+')').html("£" + result); 
}
```

**in short**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input').keyup(function () {
   var result = parseFloat(this.value) - 100;
   var tdPos=$(this).parent().index();
   $('#total').find('td:eq('+tdPos+')').html("£" + result);
 });
});
```

but i always go with the first id selector one .. performance wise , first one is far better since id selector is fast and don't have to traverse though the DOM elements.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/JhJHK/6/)

[2nd fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/JhJHK/10/)

[fiddle with multiple columns](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/JhJHK/11/)

Comment: I like this one, very nice. Will have ago with the one as well see what makes my life easier. Thank you for your answer. Note: I can change the HTML. :)

Comment: well with this.. you don't need to think about you javascript function.. even if you add multiple columns to your table.. same function will work..

Comment: Hey, how can I find a input that's lower down on the same column. E.g: below id="total" in a `tr` with `id="newNumber"`. If that made sense. (I need to use this in my calculations.

Comment: Hmm, I have ran into a problem. I didn't realise this was a thing but I don't think this will work for me. I have inputs in the same columns and different rows. `this` will pick up any inputs in the column for this right?

Comment: Updated my question. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say because I'm confusing myself and no doubt confusing you and not making much sense. Also I appreciate all the effort for this.

Comment: Any chance you could have another go at this? I'm still stuck and your example is pretty dam close. Just need it working for multiply inputs in the same column.

Comment: here you go... this is just to get you started.. added respective class to each `tr` check out in html.. you need to check for `Nan` while adding and subtracting and validation stuff..which i guess you can do it... http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/J4ALs/6/

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`. And some rules to your IDs :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        cal($(this));
    });
});

function cal(input) {
    var cal1 = parseFloat(input.val()),
        result = cal1 - 100;
    $('#' + input.attr("id") + "left").html("£" + result);
}
```

What I suggest here is that you name your result fields like your inputs and append "left". Then you send `$(this)` as input to your `cal` function. It will be a reference to the element the `keyup` event was triggered on. To reference the output/result cell you get the input field's ID and concatenate it with "left".

Hope it helps. Code is untested :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `parseFloat(input.val())` since you're passing in a jQuery object? The last line should probably read `$('#' + input.prop('id') + 'left').text(....);`

Comment: You're right about `val()` - I've updated that. According to my tests you can get the ID with `attr('id')`. Whether to use `html()` or `text()` doesn't matter much. I don't know if there are any performance differences, but since `text()` escapes the input it could be slower(?).

Comment: You could get the ID with `attr` in previous versions of jQuery, but I was under the impression that they wanted us to use `prop()`. In any case you'll need to prepend a `#`. I chose `text()` since that seems to be the intended semantics, but `html()` will work as well (although not capitalized :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        cal(this);
    });
});

function cal(obj) {
    var cal1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(obj.id).value);

    result = cal1 - 100;
    if(obj.id=='money1'){
    document.getElementById("moneyleft1").innerHTML = "£" + result;
    }else{
         document.getElementById("moneyleft2").innerHTML = "£" + result;
    }
}
```

Also change the id as it should be unique.

```
<td id="moneyleft1"></td>
<td id="moneyleft2"></td>
```

**[DEMO Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/JhJHK/2/)**

For multiple `<td>`  you should try this

```
function cal(obj) {
    var cal1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(obj.id).value);

    result = cal1 - 100;var $this = $(this);
    var cellIndex = $(obj).parent().index();
    $(obj).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).html("£"+result);

}
```

**[NEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JhJHK/12/)**

Comment: Your demo links to my original one (you should change that) but this is looking promising. Let me have a pay around with it a little. Also no need for the second part, that `ID` was a typo.

Comment: This will take me a little time to implement into my real one so don't wait about. I will comment when I know if this does the trick for me. Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: haha, Ruddy thinks we all just sit here with baited breath, waiting for the OP to let us know what he thinks of our answers. :)

Comment: @Barmar Dam it, I'm the only one that does that!? xD

Comment: Isn't `document.getElementById(obj.id).value` exactly the same as `obj.value`?

Comment: One suggestion, if there be more than two inputs then you will have to change the if conditions, I have only considered there are only two inputs

Comment: @thebjorn, yes both are same ;-)

Comment: @anand4tech I maybe not great at Javascript etc but im not that bad with it. Worked that one out for myself :P.

Comment: @Ruddy, I did't mean that,I just tried to help you so that you could solve problem in less time...never mind :-)

Comment: @Rudy, I have created a script that will work for n number of inputs.

Comment: @anand4tech I updated my question (alot!) due to things I didn't see when writing the question. Any help with it now would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This answer takes advantage of the inputs and outputs being in corresponding columns of the table, instead of constructing IDs like the other answers.

HTML:

```
<tr id="money">
    <td>Money</td>
    <td>
        <input />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="moneyleft">
    <td>Money Left</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#money input").keyup(function () {
        var pos = $(this).parent().index();
        var result = parseFloat($(this).val()) - 100;
        $("#moneyleft").children().eq(pos).text("£" + result);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/JhJHK/9/)

UPDATE:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option1</th>
        <th>Option2</th>
        <th>Option3</th>
        <th>Option4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="money">
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="upfront">
        <td>Upfront</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="overallPrice">
        <td>Overall Price</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="discount">
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="discountPrice">
        <td>Dicount Price</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        var pos = $(this).parent().index();
        overallPrice(pos);
        discountPrice(pos);
    });
});

function overallPrice(index) {
    var money = parseFloat($("#money").children().eq(index).find("input").val());
    var upfront = parseFloat($("#upfront").children().eq(index).find("input").val());
    var result = money - upfront;
    $("#overallPrice td").eq(index).text("£" + result);
    return result;
}

function discountPrice(index) {
    var discount = parseFloat($("#discount").children().eq(index).find("input").val());
    var overall = overallPrice(index);
    var result = overall - discount;
    $("#discountPrice td").eq(index).text("£" + result);
    return result;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/JhJHK/21/)

Comment: Example of this would be nice as I can't seem to get this to run.

Comment: Updated and tested, see demo.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my question (alot!) due to things I didn't see when writing the question. Any help with it now would be great.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to extrapolate my answer to your updated question, computer programming is too complicated for you. It's just one more row, you do it exactly the same.

Comment: I posted an updated answer that does the overall and discount calculations using similar technique.

Comment: "computer programming is too complicated for you" - Lol, I was just having one of them moments. Pretty sure everyone has them, I even know overall this isn't that difficult of a task but it just happened to be one I got stuck on.