# Multiply results using same function displayed on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Again with this one I have no idea what to call it but I will attempt to explain it the best I can.

I created a question similar to this before that did get answered but only because I wasn't 100% sure what I was looking for. Now I have worked out what I need etc..

So I have created this example, you will see that there are multiple inputs but they only work in the first column (due to no knowing how to make the others work). So now I need to get that working in ALL other columns using the same functions.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J4ALs/)

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option1</th>
        <th>Option2</th>
        <th>Option3</th>
        <th>Option4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="money" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Upfront</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="upfront" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Overall Price</td>
        <td id="overallPrice"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="discount" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dicount Price</td>
        <td id="discountPrice"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        overallPrice();
        discountPrice();
    });
});

function overallPrice() {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("money").value);
    cal2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("upfront").value);
    result = cal1 - cal2;
    document.getElementById("overallPrice").innerHTML = "£" + result;
    return result;
}

function discountPrice() {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("discount").value);
    cal2 = overallPrice();
    result = cal2 - cal1;
    document.getElementById("discountPrice").innerHTML = "£" + result;
}
```

So we have 2 inputs that will create the "Overall Price" and then the 3rd input will take that number and give the "Discount Price". If this was just 1 single column I could do it no problem but as I need this to work for all of the columns I'm not sure how I can do this using the same functions.

Hope this made some sort of sense if not let me know and I will try explain some more.

Here is a link to my other question, I added this part onto the end of it just encase you want to see where I started etc.

[**Other Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700435/multiple-calculations-display-on-same-page)

*Note: There will be more then 2 sets of inputs, this is just an example. In my real version some of the inputs will not be used for certain columns and I will have to change some function to calculate certain columns differently. *

Comment: so its working fine on first set? but not on other sets?

Comment: Because the other cells (`td` tags) have no id/class assigned to them, so when you write  `document.getElementById("money").value` it's only referring to the first cell in each row.

Comment: are you using same ids for other inputs(of other sets)?

Comment: @MujtabaHaider It works fine on the first because that's the only way I know how to create it. I don't know how to use the same functions that the first column is using for the other columns as well.

Comment: @tewathia No, you misunderstand. Try reading my question again. I want all the columns to use there separate inputs, column one will use the 3 inputs it has, column 2 will use its 3 inputs etc. So you can type in all different numbers and using the same function it will calculate them and display it there own separate columns.

Comment: @Ruddy Don't you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/J4ALs/5/)?

Comment: @tewathia Hmm... that looks very promising. Let me try implement this and see if it works how I want it to.

Comment: @Ruddy I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/J4ALs/5/), using classes instead of id's. Have a look

Comment: @tewathia I would put that as an answer and if possible explaining it a little for me. I will +1 as it is pretty dam good, may be the correct answer too.

Comment: Hi, You must use dynamic ids for this kind of problems. For example first set of inputs must have ids like "money_input_1",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ignitor/A4DVt/)

The idea is to find out which column the input is in (using `.index()`) and hand that index on to the `overallPrice()` and `discountPrice()` functions.

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option1</th>
        <th>Option2</th>
        <th>Option3</th>
        <th>Option4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="money">
        <td>Money</td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="upfront">
        <td>Upfront</td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="overallPrice">
        <td>Overall Price</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="discount">
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="discountPrice">
        <td>Dicount Price</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $row = $this.closest('tr'),
            $column = $this.closest('td'),
            columnIndex = $row.find('td').index($column[0]);
        //overallPrice(columnIndex);
        discountPrice(columnIndex);
    });
});

function overallPrice(column) {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat($('#money td').eq(column).find('input').val() || '0');
    cal2 = parseFloat($('#upfront td').eq(column).find('input').val() || '0');
    result = cal1 - cal2;
    $('#overallPrice td').eq(column).text("£" + result);
    return result;
}

function discountPrice(column) {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat($('#discount td').eq(column).find('input').val() || '0');
    cal2 = overallPrice(column);
    result = cal2 - cal1;
    $('#discountPrice td').eq(column).text("£" + result);
}
```

Comment: Btw: I changed `$('input').keyup()` to `$('input').change()` and it is not necessary to call both `overallPrice()` and `discountPrice()` in the event handler since `discountPrice()` is calling `overallPrice()` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a custom attribute to the individual cells(I've used `count`) and then accessing all the cells in the same column using that attribute(using the `parentElement.childNodes` thing wouldn't work because the parent in this instance would be the row, and not the column). I've passed the `count` value to your `overallPrice` and `discountPrice` functions, and modified the HTML a bit.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        discountPrice(this.attributes.count.value);
    });
});


function discountPrice(n) {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("discount")[n-1].value);
    cal2 = overallPrice(n);
    result = cal2 - cal1;
    document.getElementsByClassName("discountPrice")[n-1].innerHTML = "£" + result;
}

function overallPrice(n) {
    var cal1, cal2, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("money")[n-1].value);
    cal2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("upfront")[n-1].value);
    result = cal1 - cal2;
    document.getElementsByClassName("overallPrice")[n-1].innerHTML = "£" + result;
    return result;
}
```

**HTML** Your rows should look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Overall Price</td>
    <td count="1" class="overallPrice"></td>
    <td count="2" class="overallPrice"></td>
    <td count="3" class="overallPrice"></td>
    <td count="4" class="overallPrice"></td>
</tr>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/J4ALs/8/)

Edit: This can be done even without adding a new(count) attribute. Instead of passing the `this.attributes.count.value` to the two price functions, you can do:

```
$('input').change(function () {
        discountPrice($(this).parent().prevAll().length);
});
```

[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/J4ALs/12/)

Comment: @Ruddy I've explained it a bit, let me know if you have any questions